# Do people still study Frame Semantics?

Tags: semantics, lexical-semantics

Do people still study Frame Semantics?

As an elective, many year ago, I took one course in a topic called Semantics.  I remember my professor saying that dictionaries are problematic since they try to tell you one particular meaning of a word is better than another.  So she does not like this at all: Webester's Dictionary, Roget's Thesauraus -- forget it!

Instead she suggested we look at word relationships and frames.

- [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) is a website where one can look up words and find various senses and related words.  A **house** can be

  - a place where someone lives
  - an aristocratic family line
  - a casino (e.g. "the house always wins")
  - etc.
- [FrameNet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/)  I understood frames less, but it's sort of like each word comes with a "frame" describing how it is used:

  - Milton [TOOK](https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Taking) the can of beer out of the refrigerator.
  - An Agent removes a Theme from a Source so that the it is in the Agent's possession. 
    Milton TOOK the can of beer out of the refrigerator.
  - I [GOT](https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/frameIndex.xml?frame=Getting) two whistles from John.
  - A Recipient starts off without the Theme in their possession, and then comes to possess it.

It's not hard to find resources on Google (e.g. [here](https://prezi.com/fhr4t9jeko48/fillmores-scenes-and-frames-semantics-and-their-use-in-translation/)) but I am not a linguist and I can't tell one way or the other.  Does this theory still exist?  Does it get applied outside of very specialized settings?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly still exists, and FrameNet in particular is an active project; I know a couple of people who work on it. Not quite sure what you mean about whether it gets applied outside of specialized settings. Semantics is a relatively small subfield of linguistics (in terms of people who work on it, I mean, as compared with e.g. phonology or syntax), but frame semantics is definitely among the theories that semanticists work with these days, in the US anyway.

Comment: FrameNet's proposal seems very persuasive even if the frames themselves are somewhat bulky.  They seem natural in many contexts even if culturally we are accustomed to looking at a dictionary for reference.